# Scala, Circe, Json - how to remove parent node from json?

Tags: json, scala, scala-cats, circe

I have a json structure like this:

```
"data" : {
  "fields": {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Now I would like to remove `fields` node and keep data in `data`:

```
"data" : {
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": "value2"
 }
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
val result = data.hcursor.downField("fields").as[JsonObject].toOption.head.toString
```

but I got a strange result, instead of just json in string format

I also tried:

```
val result = data.hcursor.downField("fields").top.head.toString
```

but it was the same as:

```
val result = data.toString
```

and it includes `fields`.

How I should change my code to remove `fields` root and keep data under `data` property?

Comment: I don't see here any modification operations, only reads. Did you post all code you wanted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full working solution that traverses the JSON, extracts the fields, removes them and then merges them under `data`:

```
import io.circe.Json
import io.circe.parser._

val s =
  """
    |{
    |"data": {
    |  "fields": {
    |    "field1": "value1",
    |    "field2": "value2"
    |  }
    |}
    |}
    |""".stripMargin

val modifiedJson =
  for {
    json <- parse(s)
    fields <- json.hcursor
                .downField("data")
                .downField("fields")
                .as[Json]
    modifiedRoot <- json.hcursor
                      .downField("data")
                      .downField("fields")
                      .delete
                      .root
                      .as[Json]
    res <-
      modifiedRoot.hcursor
        .downField("data")
        .withFocus(_.deepMerge(fields))
        .root
        .as[Json]
  } yield res
```

Yields:

```
Right({
  "data" : {
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2"
  }
})
```